# SQL Server Reporting Services - how to manage a Test, Develop and Production environment?

Tags: svn, deployment, reporting-services

I Googled and checked StackEx as well, and could not find a direct paper or article on how to properly achieve separate environments when developing SSRS2005 reports. My apologies.

How can I setup SSRS2005 for one guy to develop, another guy to test and myself to control, QA and deploy into Production?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can start by creating 3 separate environments...

-development
-quality assurance
-production

This will be as simple as either creating three instances of SSRS on the same server or 3 completely seperate installations on different servers.

If you follow this structure then all three spheres can be done in tandem development, testing and production deployment/availability.

Unfortunately SSRS does not have any native deployment tools that im aware of that can deploy reports from one environment to the next. Such tools though do exist and can either be bought or developed inhouse.

You will also notice that SSRS does not have any form of built in version control etc. But again there are third party tools for this.

Hopefully this post helps! You might want to add more specific details to your question as at the moment your question is quite vague.

Comment: Thanks for that, but my question is pretty simple - how can I set up three separate SRSS environments? Ideally I would like to have one instance of SRSSS (one license) and share the development across all three environments. Can it be done or do I have to buy licenses from MS for as you say installing three separate copies of SSRS? I apologise for the vagueness, but I am really asking is where can I get more information about setting up multiple environments. So far all my searches assume ONE license, ONE database, ONE server. Surely that is not what really happens in the real world?